# Render String as a Library Attribute in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.1

I want to render an array which contains a string value as a library attribute but Line number 3 throws an error.

```
color_maps = ['AUTUMN','BONE', 'COOL', 'HOT', 'HSV', 'JET', 'OCEAN', 'PINK', 'RAINBOW','SPRING', 'SUMMER', 'WINTER']
image = cv2.imread('hurricane katrina 1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image_color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2."COLORMAP_" + color_maps[0])
```

How will I do that in Python?

Comment: You cannot compose constant literal names by using string concatenation. Instead you should edit your list as: `color_maps = [cv2.COLORMAP_AUTUMN, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE...]` and then call the `applyColorMap` as: `image_color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(image, color_maps[0])`

Comment: @ZdaR --> still throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *getattr* built-in function:

```
color_maps = ['AUTUMN','BONE', 'COOL', 'HOT', 'HSV', 'JET', 'OCEAN', 'PINK', 'RAINBOW','SPRING', 'SUMMER', 'WINTER']
image = cv2.imread('hurricane katrina 1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image_color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(image, getattr(cv2,"COLORMAP_" + color_maps[0]))
```